# How can I set the number of decimals on a popup using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, geojson

I have a popup on a website that displays values from a geoJSON file. Right now, it looks as in the picture below:
[image]

This is the current code:

```js
function popUp_cc_210303(f, l) {
  var out = [];
  if (f.properties) {
    var url =
      '<a href=/uas_tools/crop_analysis/index.php?crop=Wheat&year=2021&location=Amarillo&sublocation=Irrigation';
    var parameters = '';
    for (key in f.properties) {
      out.push(key + ': ' + f.properties[key]);
      parameters += '&' + key.replace(/\ /g, '_') + '=' + f.properties[key];
    }
    url +=
      parameters.replace(/\ /g, '%20') + " target='_blank'>Growth analysis</a>";
    out.push(url);
    var url2 =
      '<a href=/uas_tools/variety_analysis/index.php?crop=Wheat&year=2021&location=Amarillo&sublocation=Irrigation';
    url2 += " target='_blank'>Variety analysis</a>";
    out.push(url2);
    l.bindPopup(out.join('<br />'));
  }
}
```

I am trying to use `out.push(key+": "+f.properties[key].toFixed(2));` but it does not work.

This is the geoJSON file structure

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Row name": "row-1", "Col": "1", "plot_num": "?436", "plot_name": "?AOBS", "join_key": "?AOBS?436", "CC201014": 0.0, "CC201104": 0.0016344676538850001, "CC201120": 0.56401258728343395, "CC201217": 8.3524346613304221, "CC210113": 7.7746312091202094, "CC210224": 9.7393145428079926, "CC210303": 7.673018393542411, "CC210311": 14.576431943872961, "CC210323": 31.081778483525209, "CC210331": 30.067189249720045, "CC210408": 62.738628486108894, "CC210412": 63.94711538461538, "CC210418": 73.721694264987974, "CC210423": 70.039654826897262, "CC210430": 98.045130406889243, "CC210504": 91.969625530436502, "CC210510": 93.321666364934728, "CC210517": 85.521939491083955, "CC210525": 88.782478347768162, "CC210601": 95.859434682964093, "CC210607": 15.974798327739503, "CC210610": 0.0085470085470090006, "CC210614": 0.0, "CC210617": 0.0 }
```

Comment: *"but it does not work"* What happens? (maybe the values are already strings?)

Comment: Since we don't know the shape of your data there isn't much we can help with here

Comment: It does not load the map layer with popup. No error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toFixed()` method only works on floats, it appears you may have a string. You could parse it to a float first.

```
out.push(key + ': ' + parseFloat(f.properties[key]).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Actually you should use check the `typeof blabla === "number" ? blabla.toFixed(2) : ...` since data contains `string`s as well.

Answer (score 0):

One-liners are not your friend. JavaScript has its own ideas about priority. To force "order of operation", use parenthesis around any important group. Even then, code editors may format, prettify, or remove the parenthesis. Good luck finding the error then! It is best to isolate any complex operation in a named variable. A named variable is more descriptive and easier to read and reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the code is calling toFixed on all values, even if the value is a string.

```js
for (key in f.properties) {
    //The first few prperties are strings, this is throwing an error as String.prototype.toFixed is not defined, so you can't call it.
    out.push(key + ': ' + parseFloat(f.properties[key]).toFixed(2));
    parameters += '&' + key.replace(/\ /g, '_') + '=' + f.properties[key];
}
```

Try this instead

```js
for (var key in f.properties) {//include var to not add key to global scope
    var val = f.properties[key]
    if (typeof val === "number") {val = val.toFixed(2)}
    out.push(key + ': ' + val);
    parameters += '&' + key.replace(/\ /g, '_') + '=' + val;
}
```

Also, as noted in other answers, the values with floates might still be strings, if this is the case, you could try:

```
for (var key in f.properties) {//include var to not add key to global scope
    var val = f.properties[key]
    if (Number.isNaN(Number(val))) val = Number(val).toFixed(2)
    out.push(key + ': ' + val);
    parameters += '&' + key.replace(/\ /g, '_') + '=' + val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `Array.reduce()` method:

```
var out = Object.keys(f.properties)
  .reduce((a, c) => (typeof f.properties[c] === `number` ?
    a.push(`${c}: ${f.properties[c].toFixed(2)}`) :
    a.push(`${c.replace(/\s/, `_`).toLowerCase()}: ${f.properties[c]}`), a), [])
```

```js
const f = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "Row name": "row-1",
    "Col": "1",
    "plot_num": "?436",
    "plot_name": "?AOBS",
    "join_key": "?AOBS?436",
    "CC201014": 0.0,
    "CC201104": 0.0016344676538850001,
    "CC201120": 0.56401258728343395,
    "CC201217": 8.3524346613304221,
    "CC210113": 7.7746312091202094,
    "CC210224": 9.7393145428079926,
    "CC210303": 7.673018393542411,
    "CC210311": 14.576431943872961,
    "CC210323": 31.081778483525209,
    "CC210331": 30.067189249720045,
    "CC210408": 62.738628486108894,
    "CC210412": 63.94711538461538,
    "CC210418": 73.721694264987974,
    "CC210423": 70.039654826897262,
    "CC210430": 98.045130406889243,
    "CC210504": 91.969625530436502,
    "CC210510": 93.321666364934728,
    "CC210517": 85.521939491083955,
    "CC210525": 88.782478347768162,
    "CC210601": 95.859434682964093,
    "CC210607": 15.974798327739503,
    "CC210610": 0.0085470085470090006,
    "CC210614": 0.0,
    "CC210617": 0.0
  }
};
const urls = [
  `/uas_tools/crop_analysis/index.php`,
  `/uas_tools/variety_analysis/index.php`
];

const div = document.createElement('div');

Object.keys(f.properties)
  .reduce((a, c) => (typeof f.properties[c] === `number` ?
    a.push(`${c}: ${f.properties[c].toFixed(2)}`) :
    a.push(`${c.replace(/\s/, `_`).toLowerCase()}: ${f.properties[c]}`), a), [])
  .map(el => {
    const br = document.createElement('br');
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerText = el;
    div.appendChild(span).appendChild(br);
  });

const parameters = {
  crop: `Wheat`,
  year: 2021,
  location: `Amarillo`,
  sublocation: `Irrigation`
};

urls.map(pathName => {
  const url = new URL(pathName, window.location.origin);
  Object.keys(parameters)
    .map(elem => url.searchParams.set(elem, parameters[elem]));
  const br = document.createElement('br');
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url.toString();
  a.target = `_blank`;
  a.innerText = url.pathname
    .split(`/`)
    .slice(-2, -1)[0]
    .split(`_`)
    .map(el => el.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + el.substr(1).toLowerCase())
    .join(` `);
  div.appendChild(a).appendChild(br);
});

document.querySelector(`body`).appendChild(div);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```